# <tr class="TRSpacer"></tr> is being removed from my aspx files automatically

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

For some odd reason, and I have not been able to nail down exactly when, it seems to be random, this line all through my aspx files is being wiped out. It doesn't matter what file it is. Something retriggers a refactoring of the code for some reason and it always winds up missing the same lines

```
<tr class="TRSpacer"></tr>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to help solve this?

ASP.Net, Visual Studio 2012, C#, utilizing master pages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well someone else has found exactly [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t726510-re-visual-studio-2010-removing-colspan-from-td.html) - what they describe as an horrendous bug. It seems as if it is removing elements that it deems as invalid. I think in your case the absence of a `td` tag probably won't help.

What about using

```
<tr class="TRSpacer"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

It might like that more.

Comment: I know its doing its job and taking out what it deems as invalid tags but is there any way that you know of to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure your table row is properly placed in a table

next hit CRTL + F , search `.TRSpacer` , and make sure you haven't done anything to that class to make it hidden in any css you forgot about